# Is function characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions

I would like to know if function $$f(t)=\frac{4\sin^2(t/2)}{5t^2(1+2t^2)}+\frac{3}{10}\exp\bigg(\frac{4}{1-4it}-4\bigg)\cos^6(2t)+\frac{1}{2(1+t^2)}$$ a characteristic function of any random variable, i.e. there exist random variable $\xi$ such that $$f(t)=\mathbb{E}e^{it\xi}.$$ I have no idea about solution of these problem.

Comment: Yes. Hints: 1) a product of cf's is a cf; 2) a convex combination of cfs is a cf.

Comment: $|f(t)| \to \infty$ as $ t \to 0$ so it is not a characteristic function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, $\sin x / x$ ...

Comment: Ah, ok, I guess there is a spare square near $t$...

Comment: @zhoraster I see a $t^{2}$ in the denominator.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, yes, sorry

Comment: zhoraster, you are right